# ошибка при конвертации даты

Tags: ruby

При конвертации дат получаю ошибку `strptime': invalid date (ArgumentError)`

```
#test.rb

require 'date'

dates_raw =['2 июня 2016', '5 мая 2016', '10 октября 2016']

dates = []

dates_raw.each do |date_raw|
  dates.push(
    date =  Date.strptime(date_raw, "%e %m %Y")
  )
end

puts dates
```

В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что Ruby без дополнительной интернационализации ничего не знает о русских названиях месяцев и не может их корректно распарсить. Вам придется либо озаботиться интернационализацией (задействовав какой нибудь гем или открыв класс `Date`), либо просто заменить русские названия месяцев на их числовые эквиваленты

```
require 'date'

MONTHES = {
  'января'   => 1,
  'февраля'  => 2,
  'марта'    => 3,
  'апреля'   => 4,
  'мая'      => 5,
  'июня'     => 6,
  'июля'     => 7,
  'августа'  => 8,
  'сентября' => 9,
  'октября'  => 10,
  'ноября'   => 11,
  'декабря'  => 12
}.freeze

dates_raw =['2 июня 2016', '5 мая 2016', '10 октября 2016']

dates = dates_raw.collect do |date_raw|
  MONTHES.each { |rus, number| date_raw.sub!(rus, number.to_s) }
  Date.strptime(date_raw, "%e %m %Y")
end

puts dates
```

Вот вариант с переопределением метода `strptime` на уровне класса `Date`

```
require 'date'

class << Date
  MONTHES = {
    'января'   => 1,
    'февраля'  => 2,
    'марта'    => 3,
    'апреля'   => 4,
    'мая'      => 5,
    'июня'     => 6,
    'июля'     => 7,
    'августа'  => 8,
    'сентября' => 9,
    'октября'  => 10,
    'ноября'   => 11,
    'декабря'  => 12
  }.freeze

  alias strptime_orig strptime

  def strptime(date, format, klass = nil)
    MONTHES.each { |rus, number| date = date.sub(rus, number.to_s) }
    strptime_orig(date, format)
  end
end

dates_raw =['2 июня 2016', '5 мая 2016', '10 октября 2016']
dates = dates_raw.collect { |date_raw| Date.strptime(date_raw, "%e %m %Y") }

puts dates
```

Однако, на последний вариант смотрят довольно косо, так как он вмешивается в работу широко-распространенного класса и такой Monkey-patching не очень приветствуется, так как может поломать что-то из уже существующего ПО и отладить эту ситуацию будет довольно сложно.

PS Я немного отрефакторил ваш пример, чтобы он выглядел более характерно для Ruby-кода. Обычно, когда нужно преобразовать массив, используют collect-итерратор. Он позволяет избежать лишней строки `dates = []`.

Comment: Большое спасибо за подробный ответ. Есть небольшая подпроблема, как добавить 0 в номер месяца?

Comment: @alexin Просто замените в хэше числа строками, т.е. вместо 1 пишите '01'.